# How can I do right routes and controllers with swoole in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, sockets, swoole

I installed everything according to the instructions and the project started:
[image]

I read [wiki](https://github.com/swooletw/laravel-swoole/wiki) on Github,and  on point 7 was this rout example:

```
Websocket::on('connect', function ($websocket, Request $request) {
    // called while socket on connect
    $websocket->emit('message', 'hello world');
});

Websocket::on('disconnect', function ($websocket) {
    // called while socket on disconnect
});

Websocket::on('example', function ($websocket, $data) {
    $websocket->emit('message', 'response from example action');
});

Websocket::on('message', function ($websocket, $data) {
    $websocket->emit('message', 'response from message action');
    // $websocket->push('message', 'response from message action by push');
});

Websocket::on('test', 'Users/Telegram@connectServers');
Websocket::on('joinToRoom', 'Users/Telegram@joinToRoom');
```

Now, when it’s connecting (I use [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-socket-client/lifhekgaodigcpmnakfhaaaboididbdn) for tests) there is just a message `hello word` and every message I used to send, have no answer.

Why?

How can I do right routes and controllers with **swoole** in **laravel**?

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here. Try to put complete namespace for the controller.

Somthing like:

```
Websocket::on('test', '\App\Http\Controllers\Users\Telegram@connectServers');
```

It would be great if it worked with the shorted form.